# Application.Filedialog support in Mac excel 2011

Tags: macos, vba, excel-2011

Couple of questions

- Is Application.Filedialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) support in Mac excel 2011 vba?
- Difference between Application.Filedialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) and Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs)?

Comment: No, it isn't supported as the file dialog on Mac doesn't belong directly to the office program but to mac. I believe there would be a workaround with applescript though.

Answer (score 2):

I've just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410565/saveas-function-works-on-microsoft-pc-but-not-on-mac/37411960#37411960) and your question here was referenced.

To also support your questions: -

**Is Application.Filedialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) support in Mac excel 2011 vba?**

No it is not, however there is a built in function in Mac VBA called `MacScript`, which you pass applescript through to get a value back, see my previously linked thread for more detail on this.

**Difference between Application.Filedialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) and Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs)?**

[Application.Filedialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193689.aspx) gives access to four file dialog style boxes: -

- **Open dialog box** - lets users select one or more files that you can then open in the host application using the Execute method.
- **SaveAs dialog box** - lets users select a single file that you can then save the current file as using the Execute method.
- **File Picker dialog box** - lets users select one or more files. The file paths that the user selects are captured in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
- **Folder Picker dialog box** - lets users select a path. The path that the user selects is captured in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.

[Application.Dialogs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839409.aspx) gives access to all [built in dialogs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194519.aspx) available in Excel, one of which is the 'SaveAs' dialog.