Save As Macro working on PC but results in error on MAC
I have an excel macro which I use to strip formulas / delete sheets from a workbook, then open a save as dialog box with the desired file name pre-populated - this works fine on PC but falls over on MAC - relevant code below - the macro fails at .InitialFileName = FileName when run on a MAC
Any ideas how to resolve?
Many thanks
Chris
Dim FileName As String
FileName = Range("A1").Text & " " & Format(Date, "DDMMYY")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Dim fPth As Object
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)


With fPth
.InitialFileName = FileName
.Title = "Save your File"
.FilterIndex = 1
.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
If .Show <> 0 Then
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=.SelectedItems(1), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End If
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Run time 91 error code..........

So have you examined the filename after it is created and before use? Is it acceptable on the Mac?

See how I create a filename for this macro - used on a Mac... https://stackoverflow.com/a/30584013/4961700 Give it a vote if it helps.

Example file name would be like this - not sure there is anything that would upset a Mac but have had asked the user to check
PURCHASE ORDER EW2157-PL 021024.xlsx
Appreciate the suggestion

What version of Excel ? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416802/

All MS365 users so should be the absolute latest versions -
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2409 Build 16.0.18025.20030) 64-bit

I don't believe that FileDialog is supported on Mac.

I believe you are correct Rory - thanks

I highly recommend Ron de Bruin his Mac Excel pages for this: https://macexcel.com/examples/filesandfolders/
