# FileDialog Late Binding not working on MAC Excel Version 15.19

Tags: excel, vba, macos

**Introduction**: I have been using the same code (below) for `FileDialog` with **Late Binding** for PC and also MAC for a long time.

**My Problem**: Some new MACs in my company which have newer Office version for MAC, Version 15.1 and above, get the following:

> Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

At the following line:
`Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(3)`

Any ideas what modification needed to be made to make it work with Office Ver 15.1 for MAC?

***My Code***

```
Option Explicit

Function OpenXLSFileName(strPath As String, MediaName As String) As String

Dim xlsFileName As String
Dim fDialog As Object

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(3) ' <-- get the error here (msoFileDialogFilePicker = 3)

' FileDialog properties
With fDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select data records file for media " & MediaName
    .InitialFileName = strPath

    ' Add filters
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls;*.xlsx;*.csv"

    If .Show = -1 Then  ' -1 means success
        OpenXLSFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "No Excel file selected !", vbExclamation, "Warning"
        OpenXLSFileName = ""
    End If
End With
Set fDialog = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Is this thread related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960873/application-filedialog-support-in-mac-excel-2011 ?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij somehow, not exactly.